# Last 24 hours query not working in SFMC Automation Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sql, automationstudio

The query we've been using for another use case for a few months, is not working on the current automation in which we want to send a journey email to customers who registered on our website in the last 24 hours. The key field for this is Registration_Date (SFMC field type: Date), but for some reason it's not producing results as it is in other automations. Here is how the registration date value example looks like in the data extension: Thursday, July 20, 2021 12:00 AM

The code we are using (worked before, but not in this case):

```
SELECT UserID, Email, Registration_Date, First_Name, Last_Name
FROM Staging_Journey
WHERE CAST(Registration_Date as date)>CAST(getdate()-1 as date) // we tried also Registration_Date > dateadd(hh,-24,getdate()) //
```

Comment: Can you try `WHERE convert(varchar, Registration_Date, 0)>CAST(getdate()-1 as date)`?

Comment: It worked! Thanks! For my understanding, why do we need to convert a field to string since it's already set up as "Date" ?

Comment: I'll add this as an answer and explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert your date to a correct format, this this should work:

```
SELECT UserID, Email, Registration_Date, First_Name, Last_Name
FROM Staging_Journey
WHERE convert(varchar, Registration_Date, 0)>CAST(getdate()-1 as date)
```

Why do you need to convert it?

The `getdate()` function returns a date in the following format: `Jul 20 2021 12:00AM`

While your date is in this format: `Thursday, July 20, 2021 12:00 AM`